# Calling a JPanel from within a JPanel that resides in a JFrame - in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

(Edited)

I'm creating a small project with dynamically changing panels.

I've been able to write code that can call a JPanel using an action event from a button within the the JFrame (ManagerScreen). For example:

```
package route66.JFrames;


import route66.pannels.BuyReserve;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import route66.pannels.Buy;
import route66.pannels.BuyReport;
import route66.pannels.CustomerDetails;
import route66.pannels.NewUser;
import route66.pannels.QuotPanel;
import route66.pannels.ReportPanel;
import route66.pannels.Salaries_Com;
import route66.pannels.SaleSucces;

/**
*
* @author Vavu
*/
public class ManagerScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
Buy BuyPanel = new Buy();
Buy b = new Buy();
BuyReserve buyR = new BuyReserve();
BuyReport brep = new BuyReport();
CustomerDetails cusD = new CustomerDetails();
QuotPanel QP = new QuotPanel();
ReportPanel RP = new ReportPanel();
NewUser NW = new NewUser();
Salaries_Com SalCom = new Salaries_Com();
SaleSucces SalS = new SaleSucces();

boolean visible;

/**
 * Creates new form ManagerScreen
 * @param pabel
 */
public ManagerScreen() {

  initComponents();

  DynamicPanel.setLayout(layout);     
  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 0;

  DynamicPanel.add(b,c);
  DynamicPanel.add(buyR,c);
  DynamicPanel.add(brep,c);
  DynamicPanel.add(cusD,c);
  DynamicPanel.add(QP,c);
  DynamicPanel.add(RP,c);
  DynamicPanel.add(NW,c);
  DynamicPanel.add(SalCom,c);
  DynamicPanel.add(SalS,c);


    b.setVisible(false);
    buyR.setVisible(false);
    brep.setVisible(false);
    cusD.setVisible(false);
    QP.setVisible(false);
    RP.setVisible(false);
    NW.setVisible(false);
    SalCom.setVisible(false);
    SalS.setVisible(false);


}



/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    DynamicPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    MSbuy = new javax.swing.JButton();
    MSQuotation = new javax.swing.JButton();
    MSReserve = new javax.swing.JButton();
    MSSalCom = new javax.swing.JButton();
    MSReport = new javax.swing.JButton();
    MSCreateNew = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(980, 740));
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    DynamicPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    DynamicPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
    DynamicPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
    DynamicPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 500));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout DynamicPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(DynamicPanel);
    DynamicPanel.setLayout(DynamicPanelLayout);
    DynamicPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        DynamicPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 700, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    DynamicPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        DynamicPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 500, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    getContentPane().add(DynamicPanel);
    DynamicPanel.setBounds(330, 260, 700, 500);

    MSbuy.setText("Buy");
    MSbuy.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            MSbuyActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(MSbuy);
    MSbuy.setBounds(70, 480, 188, 29);

    MSQuotation.setText("Quotation");
    MSQuotation.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            MSQuotationActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(MSQuotation);
    MSQuotation.setBounds(70, 520, 188, 29);

    MSReserve.setText("Reserve");
    MSReserve.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            MSReserveActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(MSReserve);
    MSReserve.setBounds(70, 440, 188, 29);

    MSSalCom.setText("Salaries & Commission");
    MSSalCom.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            MSSalComActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(MSSalCom);
    MSSalCom.setBounds(70, 400, 188, 29);

    MSReport.setText("Report");
    MSReport.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            MSReportActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(MSReport);
    MSReport.setBounds(70, 560, 187, 29);

    MSCreateNew.setText("Create New User");
    MSCreateNew.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            MSCreateNewActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(MSCreateNew);
    MSCreateNew.setBounds(70, 600, 187, 29);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 48)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
    jLabel1.setText("ROUTE66 CAR DEALERSHIP");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
    jLabel1.setBounds(330, 0, 650, 130);

    jLabel3.setText(".");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel3);
    jLabel3.setBounds(0, 0, 330, 260);

    jLabel2.setText(".");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
    jLabel2.setBounds(330, 90, 650, 210);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void MSbuyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    b.setVisible(false);
    buyR.setVisible(true);
    brep.setVisible(false);
    cusD.setVisible(false);
    QP.setVisible(false);
    RP.setVisible(false);
    NW.setVisible(false);
    SalCom.setVisible(false);
    SalS.setVisible(false);
}                                     

private void MSSalComActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    b.setVisible(false);
    buyR.setVisible(false);
    brep.setVisible(false);
    cusD.setVisible(false);
    QP.setVisible(false);
    RP.setVisible(false);
    NW.setVisible(false);
    SalCom.setVisible(true);
    SalS.setVisible(false);
}                                        

private void MSReserveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    b.setVisible(false);
    buyR.setVisible(false);
    brep.setVisible(false);
    cusD.setVisible(false);
    QP.setVisible(false);
    RP.setVisible(true);
    NW.setVisible(false);
    SalCom.setVisible(false);
    SalS.setVisible(false);
}                                         

private void MSQuotationActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void MSReportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void MSCreateNewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ManagerScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ManagerScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ManagerScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ManagerScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {  
            new ManagerScreen().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel DynamicPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton MSCreateNew;
private javax.swing.JButton MSQuotation;
private javax.swing.JButton MSReport;
private javax.swing.JButton MSReserve;
private javax.swing.JButton MSSalCom;
private javax.swing.JButton MSbuy;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

My problem is that the BR panel (buyReserve()), containing two buttons - within the JFrame, is supposed to be able to call either the buy panel or brep panel (BuyReport()) from the within the DynamicPanel() or at least thats what I think, if that makes sense.

so basically I've tried somethings including the following:

```
 package route66.pannels;

 import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
 import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
 import route66.pannels.BuyReport;
 import route66.pannels.CustomerDetails;

 /**
 *
 * @author Vavu
 */
 public class BuyReserve extends javax.swing.JPanel {

 GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
 Buy BuyPanel = new Buy();
 Buy b = new Buy();
 BuyReserve buyR = new BuyReserve();
 BuyReport brep = new BuyReport();
 CustomerDetails cusD = new CustomerDetails();
 QuotPanel QP = new QuotPanel();
 ReportPanel RP = new ReportPanel();
 NewUser NW = new NewUser();
 Salaries_Com SalCom = new Salaries_Com();
 SaleSucces SalS = new SaleSucces();

/**
 * Creates new form BuyReserve
 */
public BuyReserve() {
    initComponents();

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    btnBuy = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnReserve = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    btnBuy.setText("New Client");
    btnBuy.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnBuyActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnReserve.setText("Reserve Client");

    jLabel1.setText("Select Option");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(144, 144, 144)
                    .addComponent(btnBuy)
                    .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                    .addComponent(btnReserve))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(230, 230, 230)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)))
            .addContainerGap(162, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(62, 62, 62)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(72, 72, 72)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnBuy)
                .addComponent(btnReserve))
            .addContainerGap(201, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnBuyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    b.setVisible(true);   
}                                      


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnBuy;
private javax.swing.JButton btnReserve;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

If I run the ManagerScreen with the inclusion of the second code snippet I get an error. I've also tried other types of code that end up saying things like the jpanel doesn't have a main class n so on.

So, hopefully by this stage I've been able to get my point across to be to able ask (again); how do I call a panel, within a panel that is inside a JFrame?

Comment: If you want the quickest help, what you really want to post is a valid [mcve], a small compilable and runnable program, one we can run unaltered and that will demonstrate your problem for us. That will be the quickest way to get us to understand your code and your problem. This should be posted as code-formatted text and not in a link.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like what you really want to do is simply use is a CardLayout. That's it.

Comment: Thanks, but it remains un-runnable as it has dependencies, including the a bunch of classes, that we have no access to. If my answer below does not answer your question, then consider using my code as a guide for how to create a small self-contained program, and then create and post one that clarifies your problem, and that we can run.

Comment: Let me do that...

Comment: From the code that u wrote, is it possible to add a Button in the lets say BuyPanel that will be able to bring up lets say a VehicleSelectPanel in the same region that the BuyPanel is occupying?

Comment: Yes. Best would be to use a MVC approach, one which I demonstrate in [this answer to a recent similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39311139/522444), but you could have code in BuyPanel call code in the containing panel in a "quick and dirty way", as I in fact demonstrate below.

Comment: I get what u saying but i don't know how to implement such, still a newbie when it comes to netbeans and java, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You state that you want to "call" JPanels, but this doesn't really have any meaning. If your goal is to *swap* JPanel views, then the simplest and easiest way is to use a CardLayout. For more on this useful tool, please see the [CardLayout Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ManagerPanel extends JPanel {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    private BuyPanel buyPanel = new BuyPanel(this);
    private BuyReportPanel buyReportPanel = new BuyReportPanel(this);
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    private JComboBox<String> panelComboBox = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);

    public ManagerPanel() {
        comboModel.addElement(BuyPanel.BUY);
        comboModel.addElement(BuyReportPanel.BUY_REPORT);
        panelComboBox.addActionListener(evt -> {
            String key = panelComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            cardLayout.show(cardLayoutPanel, key);
        });
        JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
        comboPanel.add(panelComboBox);

        cardLayoutPanel.add(buyPanel, BuyPanel.BUY);
        cardLayoutPanel.add(buyReportPanel, BuyReportPanel.BUY_REPORT);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cardLayoutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ManagerPanel mainPanel = new ManagerPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ManagerPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    public void nextPanel() {
        cardLayout.next(cardLayoutPanel);
    }
}

class BuyReportPanel extends JPanel {
    public final static String BUY_REPORT = "Buy Report";
    private ManagerPanel managerPanel;

    public BuyReportPanel(ManagerPanel managerPanel) {
        this.managerPanel = managerPanel;
        add(new JLabel(BUY_REPORT), SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(new JButton(new NextPanelAction(managerPanel)));
    }
}

class BuyPanel extends JPanel {
    public final static String BUY = "Buy";
    private ManagerPanel managerPanel;

    public BuyPanel(ManagerPanel managerPanel) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        this.managerPanel = managerPanel;
        add(new JLabel(BUY), SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(new JButton(new NextPanelAction(managerPanel)));
    }
}

class NextPanelAction extends AbstractAction {
    private ManagerPanel managerPanel;

    public NextPanelAction(ManagerPanel managerPanel) {
        super("Next Panel");
        this.managerPanel = managerPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        managerPanel.nextPanel();
    }
}
```

Note that I've passed my main class, here ManagerPanel, into other classes, and so they can call any of its public methods including `nextPanel()`, as needed.